# TFLearn failing to properly load training data with shape

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction, tflearn

I'm trying to create an AI to predict the outcome of FRC competition matches using tensorflow and TFLearn.

Here is the relevant

```
x = np.load("FRCPrediction/matchData.npz")["x"]
y = np.load("FRCPrediction/matchData.npz")["y"]

def buildModel():
    net = tflearn.input_data([10, 0])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64)
    net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 10, activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

model = buildModel()

BATCHSIZE = 128

model.fit(x, y, batch_size = BATCHSIZE)
```

It is failing with error:

```
Training samples: 36024
Validation samples: 0
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ce7cbb8e618a> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x, y, batch_size = BATCHSIZE)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126                              'which has shape %r' %
   1127                              (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name,
-> 1128                               str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1129           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1130             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 36) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 10, 0)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your X dimension is `(some_length, 36)` which can't fit your input layer with a dimension of `(10, 0)`. I doubt for your second dimension which equals to 0, the shape should at least 1.
To solve it your should do:

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 36])
```

`None` for a dynamic dimension which will match with all `BATCHSIZE`, no matter 128, 1000, or 2000